# Laravel Herd slow response using external MySQL database connection

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-valet, laravel-herd

I just picked up my MacBook M3 Pro yesterday. Till now I was a Windows user.

I've installed Laravel Herd. It's build upon the Laravel Valet package. It works very good and simple. Out of the box switching PHP versions etc. I have my website opened in Chrome and with the database pointing out to DBngin all works so fast and snappy. But when I want to connect to my real hosted Mysql Database everything is slowed down so much.

I've never had this experience with my good old Apache setup on my Windows environment, the database has enough resources to do his job and the live site works like a breeze.

But on my Mac...with DBngin it's just a wait of a fingerclick but external I have to wait like 10 seconds before I get my response. Does anybody have the same experience? And if there are any suggestions what causes this.

Comment: What about network speed and latency?

Comment: The network speed here in my office is 1gb/s this is not the issue I suppose. Also with my Windows machine the external database is reacting spot on. Same network. So strange. I would love to have the opportunity to work on the live database so now and then.

Comment: How about trying to connect to your external DB front the terminal or from MySQL workbench on the Mac? If it's fast then the issue is with herd probably.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've tried TablePlus, lightning fast. I've read about possible DNS issues, I've changed to the Google DNS but unfortunatelly no difference. I hope I can be pushed in the right direction.